# how to control Mobile jqGrid shrinkToFit

Tags: jqgrid

I want to do jqGrid shrinkToFit:false on screens of more than 320px and less than 768px. For 769px screens, I want to use shrinkToFit:true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
function shrinkToFitPixels() {
   var sreenwidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
   if( sreenwidth >= 320 && sreenwidth <= 768 ) {
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}

$("#grid").jqGrid({
...
   shrinkToFit : shrinkToFitPixels(),
...
});
```